# Why doesn't Boltzmann Approximation obey Pauli's exclusion principle?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle

The difference between Fermi–Dirac function and Boltzmann approximation is that Fermi–Dirac function considers Pauli's exclusion principle but Boltzmann approximation doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Because at the time Boltzmann died, Pauli was only six years old and had not yet formulated his Exclusion Principle. Pauli was a genius but he was not *that* precocious!